# Python Pandas Add DataRow Revision Number

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, python-3.8

I have a Data Frame looking like below. I need to use a combination of ID and Serial and calculate revision numbers.

| ID | Serial | Time | Revision |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 48ff35eb-70ad-4dcd-a441-8c7c9966a236 | ABC | 12/31/2020 8:37:13 AM |  |
| 78faedd8-a250-4e52-ac81-a29d46715a51 | PQR | 12/03/2019 1:30:00 AM |  |
| 48ff35eb-70ad-4dcd-a441-8c7c9966a236 | ABC | 12/31/2020 8:37:13 AM |  |
| 48ff35eb-70ad-4dcd-a441-8c7c9966a236 | ABC | 01/23/2021 5:18:44 PM |  |
| 78faedd8-a250-4e52-ac81-a29d46715a51 | ABC | 10/23/2020 8:01:08 AM |  |
| 48ff35eb-70ad-4dcd-a441-8c7c9966a236 | ABC | 01/20/2021 8:10:27 PM |  |

**Expected result:**

| ID | Serial | Time | Revision |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 48ff35eb-70ad-4dcd-a441-8c7c9966a236 | ABC | 12/31/2020 8:37:13 AM | 1 |
| 78faedd8-a250-4e52-ac81-a29d46715a51 | PQR | 12/03/2019 1:30:00 AM | 1 |
| 48ff35eb-70ad-4dcd-a441-8c7c9966a236 | ABC | 12/31/2020 8:37:13 AM | 1 |
| 48ff35eb-70ad-4dcd-a441-8c7c9966a236 | ABC | 01/23/2021 5:18:44 PM | 3 |
| 78faedd8-a250-4e52-ac81-a29d46715a51 | ABC | 10/23/2020 8:01:08 AM | 1 |
| 48ff35eb-70ad-4dcd-a441-8c7c9966a236 | ABC | 01/20/2021 8:10:27 PM | 2 |

I tried the following:

```
columns_of_interest = ["ID", "Serial"]
df["revision"] = df.groupby(columns_of_interest).cumcount() + 1
```

Then, I just got the row counts for each group, but how I do get accurate version numbers?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you are looking for dense `rank`:

```
# `rank` only works with numerical
df['Time'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Time'])

df['Revision'] = df.groupby(columns_of_interest)['Time'].rank(method='dense')
```

Output:

```
                                     ID Serial                Time  Revision
0  48ff35eb-70ad-4dcd-a441-8c7c9966a236    ABC 2020-12-31 08:37:13       1.0
1  78faedd8-a250-4e52-ac81-a29d46715a51    PQR 2019-12-03 01:30:00       1.0
2  48ff35eb-70ad-4dcd-a441-8c7c9966a236    ABC 2020-12-31 08:37:13       1.0
3  48ff35eb-70ad-4dcd-a441-8c7c9966a236    ABC 2021-01-23 17:18:44       3.0
4  78faedd8-a250-4e52-ac81-a29d46715a51    ABC 2020-10-23 08:01:08       1.0
5  48ff35eb-70ad-4dcd-a441-8c7c9966a236    ABC 2021-01-20 20:10:27       2.0
```

Comment: @Manakin thanks for pointing that out. I didn't look at the output carefully. updated the answer.

Answer (score 1):

Two steps, first let's drop the duplicates, sort the values and create a counter by `ID` and `Serial`.

Then we can forward fill any missing duplicate values:

```
df['Revision'] = df.index.map(df.drop_duplicates(subset=['ID','Serial','Time'],keep='first')\
                   .sort_values('Time').groupby(['ID','Serial']).cumcount() + 1)

df['Revision'] = df.groupby(['ID','Serial'])['revision'].ffill().astype(int)


                                     ID Serial                Time  Revision
0  48ff35eb-70ad-4dcd-a441-8c7c9966a236    ABC 2020-12-31 08:37:13         1
1  78faedd8-a250-4e52-ac81-a29d46715a51    PQR 2019-12-03 01:30:00         1
2  48ff35eb-70ad-4dcd-a441-8c7c9966a236    ABC 2020-12-31 08:37:13         1
3  48ff35eb-70ad-4dcd-a441-8c7c9966a236    ABC 2021-01-23 17:18:44         3
4  78faedd8-a250-4e52-ac81-a29d46715a51    ABC 2020-10-23 08:01:08         1
5  48ff35eb-70ad-4dcd-a441-8c7c9966a236    ABC 2021-01-20 20:10:27         2
```